# Cordova 9+ "Failed to fetch plugin via registry"

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

So I start a new Cordova project.

```
cordova create myprojectname com.myproject MyProject
```

I then add Android platform.

```
cordova platform add android
```

I then add iOS platform

```
cordova platform add ios
```

I then attempt to add a plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 4294963238 Error output:
npm WARN com.myproject@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT\myprojectname\node_modules\cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
npm ERR! dest C:\PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT\myprojectname\node_modules\.cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT\myprojectname\node_modules\cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine' -> 'C:\PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT\myprojectname\node_modules\.cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\PATH-TO-MY-APP-DATA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-09T01_12_38_805Z-debug.log
```

In fact, I get this error for ANY and ALL plugins I attempt to install.

I'm using Node.js Command Prompt with these versions:

```
npm: '6.14.5'
node: '12.13.1 (x64)'
cordova: '9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)'
cordova-android: '^8.1.0'
cordova-ios: '^5.1.1'
```

How can I start installing plugins?

**Update 1**
I should state that if I roll my cordova back to version 7.0.0 or below, I am able to install plugins. However, I really need to keep things up to date in order to target the new iOS 5+ platform.

Comment: Please check if you are in your projects root file.

Comment: I most definitely am.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me

Comment: Not sure about a firewall issue - if I roll my cordova back to version 7.0.0 or below, I am able to install plugins. I have edited my question to say this.

Comment: I had some intermediate issues with wkwebview, but they seem to have cleared up with cordova-ios 6.0.0. Maybe upgrade the ios piece first? Then I don't think you need to separately install wkwebview, it's the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's an answer of sorts.

When I work in a project sitting **outside** of a Dropbox directory, everything works.

Funny thing is - I've been creating/building cordova apps from within Dropbox directories for years without any issues as I'm sure many people do. So this is a bit of a head scratcher for me.

I'm not sure why yet but the answer in this case is bizarely: Work outside Dropbox.